# Prevent Hotlinking through CSS via .htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess

I've set up my htaccess this way to block hotlinking:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mydomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(bmp|dtd|flv|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|psd|swf|tif|txt|mov|mpeg|mp3|xml)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

The problem is that it works perfectly fine via HTML (such as `<img>` tags) but it doesn't prevent hotlinking through CSS (ex., `background-image: url`)

So here's a clarification on what I mean:

Server A (My Domain) hosts file /myfile.jpg
Server B (Another Domain) hosts css file /mycss.css

Server B CSS file contains `background-image:url('server-A/myfile.jpg');` This CSS rule works; it loads the jpg file from Server A.  If Server B were to also have an `<img src="server-A/myfile.jpg">`, it wouldn't load.  It just works for the CSS.  It shouldn't work for *either*.

Comment: So you know, some browsers will don't send HTTP_REFERER and legitimate users will end up seeing broken images. You probably shouldn't bother with this unless you have a really serious problem with hot linking.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "doesn't prevent hotlinking through CSS" do you mean 1) that other people can still use your existing CSS files with their pages, or 2) that other people can put your images in their own CSS files?

If 1) it may be that the referrer header for the image fetch is the CSS file itself, which will come from your server, so will fail the first RewriteCond  rule and the fetch won't be blocked.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I'll edit the main text for clarification.