# htaccess file blocking image on iPad and iPhone

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site hosted on MediaTemple.  I don't know anything about .htaccess editing, so I copied and pasted from online sources (MT and others).  I added the following lines to my .htaccess file to prevent hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(png|jpg)$ http://example.com/example.png [F]
```

The problem is of all the png and jpg image files I have on my site, one of them isn't showing up on my iPad or iPhone.  All image files are located in the same directory.

At first, none of images on my home page weren't showing up.  I did some Googling and found other ways to construct the last line, so I've tried changing [F] to [NC,F,L] and [NC,R,L] as well.  I got 2 of the 3 images to show up.  At one point, some of the images didn't even show up in my media library when logging into wp-admin on my desktop.  Everything works just fine, of course, when I comment out the lines.  I tried clearing the cache on my devices, but that didn't work either.

There is no rhyme or reason I can find.  MT tech support had no solution. Googling has turned up nothing.  Can't find an answer specific to my problem on SO, but got some insight here - [Prevent Hotlinking through CSS via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999255/prevent-hotlinking-through-css-via-htaccess) - where user states "some browsers will don't send HTTP_REFERER and legitimate users will end up seeing broken images."  But if my other images are showing up, this can't be a problem with HTTP_REFERER.

I don't have a problem with hotlinking because I don't have any images worth hotlinking, so I personally can live without this, but in the event I design a site for a client who wants to prevent hotlinking, I need to have .htaccess work.

Don't know if this matters, but I also have .htaccess files in my wp-content and wp-admin folders, too, but I don't think they're causing the problem.

Comment: Can you see the access logs? The referer, user agent, etc info should be there and would be very helpful in debugging.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that or what I'd be looking for.